# Google API PHP Client autoload.php is required but missing?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-api-php-client

Step 1: Download [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)

Step 2: Change directory name to "api" and upload to Google App Engine

Step 3: Follow [instructions](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/installation) and keep adding the following lines to because of specific errors saying files missing

```
set_include_path( get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'api/src' );
require_once 'Google/Collection.php';
require_once 'Google/Model.php';
require_once 'Google/Exception.php';
require_once 'Google/Task/Exception.php';
require_once 'Google/Service.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Resource.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Gmail.php';
```

Step 4: Receive the following error (used {...} for removed items),

```
Warning: require_once(/base/data/home/apps/{...}/api/src/Google/autoload.php): 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
/base/data/home/apps/{...}/api/src/Google/Collection.php on line 4 Fatal
error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/base/data/home/apps/{...}/api/src/Google/autoload.php'
(include_path='.;/base/data/home/{...}/;/base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk;api/src')
in /base/data/home/apps/{...}/api/src/Google/Collection.php on line 4
```

The file "Collection.php" is required by other files, but it requires "autoload.php" file. There is no "autoload.php" file. I have searched for hours and am completely lost. Why would their be a dependency of a file that doesn't exist and if it needs to be created somehow, why bury the instructions?

All I want to do is use this to check for unread emails, does the API not work? Is there another way to check a users unread emails baked into GAE?

Comment: Running composer install will give you your autoload file that you need to require.

Comment: Would this composer file be somehow specific for my installation or would it be the same for anyone who creates it? Is there simply an "autoload.php" for this program someone could share?

Doesn't this composer software simply create a list of dependencies in a specific order so they will work, couldn't I accomplish the same thing by just listing my required_once in a specific order? I've made more adjustments to them, but am now stuck with "Client.php" looking for a class called "Collection". I have every file "required_once" with "Client.php" last,  how will composer fix this if it's gone?

Comment: Howdy other mike! So the composer.json (configuration) file is generic, but when you run composer install with that generic config file there, it scans the files on your machine and creates an autoloader map file for you. You include that one file and then whenever you try to use a class that isn't defined, it checks that autoloader map and loads the appropriate file. You do not need composer on GAE, just on your computer. getcomposer.org and download composer.phar, then CD to that folder with terminal and run composer.phar install, then upload the files it generates to GAE.

Comment: Hope that makes sense, ran out of characters and have to run! Basically, you can modify composer.json to include another library (open the file, check out the library and version listing) and then run composer install and upload the changes. This allows you to quickly add a library to your project and use additional classes without having to include ANY new files. One time setup.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was able to eventually find the file, I had forgetten about Google Cache, http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:992oyuQ76a0J:https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/autoload.php+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you need is [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/3dfefdefe86f40efcbf42daf25bc086830df0c9b/src/Google/autoload.php)

`<?php
/*
 * Copyright 2014 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
function google_api_php_client_autoload($className) {
  $classPath = explode('_', $className);
  if ($classPath[0] != 'Google') {
    return;
  }
  // Drop 'Google', and maximum class file path depth in this project is 3.
  $classPath = array_slice($classPath, 1, 2);
  $filePath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . implode('/', $classPath) . '.php';
  if (file_exists($filePath)) {
    require_once($filePath);
  }
}
spl_autoload_register('google_api_php_client_autoload');`

Please try using it and let me know if It worked for you.

Comment: Yes, this worked. Thank you. Any chance you would be kind enough to direct me to the next steps after this? I have a Google App Engine application I want to create for our companies Google Apps for Work accounts. Am I supposed to use "OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications" in this scenario?

Comment: I have used it for only retrieve some data from google analytic . Search Hello Analytic and follow the tutorial and let me know where you are facing problem.after this you will have some idea you can put on your project..

Answer (score 0):

The [source shows](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Collection.php#L3-L5) what looks like a bug(?) where if it cannot find `Google_Client` then it tries to include an `autoload.php` file.

Add this as your first include

```
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
```

*edit* So yeah, not only that but it also looks like you'll need to run composer like mnv said.

Answer (score 0):

Last week, GitHub had the autoload.php file and this week it does not. I'm not too keen on using composer - call me old school

Here's the content of the autoload.php file that I had last week that might help you maybe?

```
<?php
/*
 * Copyright 2014 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

// PHP 5.2 compatibility: E_USER_DEPRECATED was added in 5.3
if (!defined('E_USER_DEPRECATED')) {
  define('E_USER_DEPRECATED', E_USER_WARNING);
}

$error = "google-api-php-client's autoloader was moved to src/Google/autoload.php in 1.1.3. This ";
$error .= "redirect will be removed in 1.2. Please adjust your code to use the new location.";
trigger_error($error, E_USER_DEPRECATED);
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/src/Google/autoload.php';
```

Comment: Weird that they removed the file. I can't compile in GAE, so I would end up compiling on another server and then uploading the generic copy. Strange they felt the need to remove a generic file that I would now have to recreate. The code you posted doesn't seem like the "autoload.php" file since most files wouldn't reference themselves. If you have the actual file, I would be ecstatic if you would post it here or somehwere on github.

Comment: Sorry, that is the file. I found it using Google Cache. http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:992oyuQ76a0J:https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/autoload.php+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Answer (score 0):

Google Cache had the file, http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:992oyuQ76a0J:https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/autoload.php+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Maybe it got removed by mistake, not sure.